# Can I prevent payment from capturing when set to "Authorize & Capture"

Tags: magento-1, payment, payment-gateway, partial-payments

Is it possible to prevent a payment method that is set to "Authorize & Capture" from capturing until I capture it manually at a later date?

I still want to authorize the payment details but not capture them.

Ideally I would like to know if there is a global solution for multiple payment methods (Authorize.net, SagePay, Stripe, etc...)

Otherwise, would it be possible to overwrite the `function capture()` of each of the payment methods separately and add an extra check before calling `parent::capture()` ?

Comment: I have tried placing the order on hold before the payment is captured but this does not seem to work.